# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite)

Tags: flutter, dart, tflite

Hello Guys i cloned a project from Github for Plant Disease Detection (Flutter , Dart) , I'm having an issue whenever i Choose the Plant image from my Computer i get this Error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite)
```

Version i'm using :

```
tflite: ^1.1.2
Flutter: ^3.13.3
```

I´ve been stuck here for almost 2 weeks Does anyone have any idea what may be the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the model file in the right repository? Also have you set up tflite the right way? It might not work if you just want to clone and run.

Comment: To be honest i just cloned it and ran it , i didn't know that you have to setup other things can you guide me please.

Comment: Please follow the setup instructions at https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter
Also, you'd need the pre-trained tflite model. If it's not present in the cloned repo, it must be available for download, please check the documentation of the repo you cloned

Comment: Ok sir , the model already exists and trained + the repository using tflite not tflite_flutter , tflite is depreacted may it be the cause of the issue ? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Sorry for missing the real library. Try connecting with the repo maintainer. Or checking the issues section. That would give an indication if the code still works with old libraries.